# Sum quantities for products

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to sum specific quantities of products but in my code, when I sum, it takes all quantities I have in my table and brings the full quantity FOR ALL PRODUCTS. Here's the example of the results...

```
CÓDIGO  QTD
288     1,153
63064   1,153
28229   1,153
```

Should be for example:

```
CÓDIGO  QTD
288     12
63064   9
28229   231
```

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
   substr(ML.msg, (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3) + 1), (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 4) - 1) - instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3)) Código,
   (SELECT
            SUM(to_number(substr(ML.msg, -9))) soma
        FROM Msg_log ML,
            item_cbo IC
        WHERE TRUNC(ML.create_date_time) = TRUNC(current_date)
        AND IC.Item_name = substr(ML.msg, (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3) + 1), (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 4) - 1) - instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3))
        AND ((ML.msg_id = 1053
        AND ML.module = 'WAVE')
        OR (ML.msg_id = 1054
        AND ML.module = 'WAVE')))
    qtd
FROM Msg_log ML,
    item_cbo IC   
WHERE TRUNC(ML.create_date_time) = TRUNC(current_date)
AND ((ML.msg_id = 1053
AND ML.module = 'WAVE')
OR (ML.msg_id = 1054
AND ML.module = 'WAVE'))
```

Comment: Just based on the context of the question, you're going to want to group by Codigo at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems - aside from needing `group by`, also your subquery repeats the logic of your outer query. And more importantly, your outer query seems to be doing a **cartesian (cross) join** between Msg_Log and item_cbo - it joins them *with no conditions*. If there's more than 1 row in `item_cbo`, you're probably getting way more results than you want.

Without any of your table data, I'm kinda guessing here, but I'd rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT
   substr(ML.msg, (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3) + 1), (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 4) - 1) - instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3)) Código,
   SUM(to_number(substr(ML.msg, -9))) qtd
FROM Msg_log ML,
    item_cbo IC
WHERE TRUNC(ML.create_date_time) = TRUNC(current_date)
AND ((ML.msg_id = 1053
AND ML.module = 'WAVE')
OR (ML.msg_id = 1054
AND ML.module = 'WAVE'))
AND IC.Item_name = substr(ML.msg, (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3) + 1), (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 4) - 1) - instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3))
GROUP BY substr(ML.msg, (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3) + 1), (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 4) - 1) - instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3));
```

Actually, wait, no - for clarity and readability, I think I'd rather write it like this:

```
SELECT Código, sum(qtd) as qtd
FROM (SELECT
           substr(ML.msg, (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3) + 1), (instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 4) - 1) - instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3)) Código,
           to_number(substr(ML.msg, -9)) qtd
        FROM Msg_log ML
        WHERE TRUNC(ML.create_date_time) = TRUNC(current_date)
        AND ((ML.msg_id = 1053
        AND ML.module = 'WAVE')
        OR (ML.msg_id = 1054
        AND ML.module = 'WAVE'))
) ML
INNER JOIN item_cbo IC
    ON IC.Item_name = ML.Código
GROUP BY Código;
```

I'm guessing that you're not actually using `item_cbo` and you could remove it entirely, but I left it in because maybe you're using it to filter your results.

Comment: u're right,  seeing this, im not using item_cbo, i removed it. i tried ur code but it didnt worked. here's the message: Data source adapter error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: sorry for the trouble, im a new user and trying to build a relatory with this.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the query isn't properly quoted in Java? Or it might be having trouble with the "ó" character. This works fine in sql*plus. You could edit your question and add the Java code where this query is being executed.

Comment: im using cognos sql from ibm.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest cleaning up the query.  I *think* this is what you are trying to do:

```
select Código,  
       sum(to_number(substr(ML.msg, -9)))) as soma
from (select ml.*,
             substr(ML.msg, instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3) + 1, instr (ML.msg, ' ', 1, 4) - 1) - instr(ML.msg, ' ', 1, 3)) as Código
      from Msg_log ml
     ) ml join
     item_cbo IC 
     on IC.Item_name = ml.Código
where trunc(ML.create_date_time) = TRUNC(current_date) and
       ((ML.msg_id = 1053 and ML.module = 'WAVE') or
        (ML.msg_id = 1054 and ML.module = 'WAVE')
       ) as qtd
group by Código;
```

Comment: hey, i tried using your code but showed this: Data source adapter error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: sorry for the trouble, im new user in sql so im trying to finish my relatory, but got stucked in this part.